# Dirac delta integral of cosx

Tags: integration, fermi-dirac-integral

I have a pboblem as: $\int_0^{2\pi } {\delta \left( {{\rm{cos}}x} \right)dx} $.

I have done this:

$\begin{array}{l}
g\left( x \right) = {\rm{cos}}x = 0 \Rightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{l}
x = \frac{\pi }{2}\\
x =  - \frac{\pi }{2}
\end{array} \right. \Rightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{l}
g'\left( {\frac{\pi }{2}} \right) =  - \sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{2}} \right) =  - 1\\
g'\left( { - \frac{\pi }{2}} \right) =  - \sin \left( { - \frac{\pi }{2}} \right) = 1
\end{array} \right.\\
 \Rightarrow \int_0^{2\pi } {\delta \left( {{\rm{cos}}x} \right)dx}  = \int_0^{2\pi } {\delta \left( {x - \frac{\pi }{2}} \right)dx}  + \int_0^{2\pi } {\delta \left( {x + \frac{\pi }{2}} \right)dx = 2 } 
\end{array}$

Howerver, my pro said that I did it wrong, and require me rethouht!!!
Where is my false? Thanks

Comment: Your set of roots of $\cos x$ is incomplete and contains roots outside of the interval in question. Domain of integration is $[0,2\pi]$, the second root in this interval is ...

Comment: Indeed, what *are* the roots of $\cos x$ inside the interval $[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: Thanks! I have done as: $\begin{array}{l}
g\left( x \right) = {\rm{cos}}x = 0 \Rightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{l}
x = \frac{\pi }{2}\\
x = \frac{{3\pi }}{2}
\end{array} \right. \Rightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{l}
g'\left( {\frac{\pi }{2}} \right) =  - \sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{2}} \right) =  - 1\\
g'\left( {\frac{{3\pi }}{2}} \right) =  - \sin \left( {\frac{{3\pi }}{2}} \right) = 1
\end{array} \right.\\
  = \int_0^{2\pi } {\delta \left( {x - \frac{\pi }{2}} \right)dx}  + \int_0^{2\pi } {\delta \left( {x - \frac{{3\pi }}{2}} \right)dx =2 } 
\end{array}$ Right????

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\delta\pars{\vphantom{\LARGE A}\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
=
\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\bracks{{\delta\pars{x - \pi/2} \over \verts{-\sin\pars{\pi/2}}}
+
{\delta\pars{x - 3\pi/2} \over \verts{-\sin\pars{3\pi/2}}}}\,\dd x
=
\color{#00f}{\large 2}
$$