# How to integrate dirac delta: $\int^\pi_0 \sin(\theta) \delta(\cos\theta - 1)\, d \theta$?

Tags: dirac-delta

The integration of

$$\int^\pi_0 \sin(\theta) \delta(\cos\theta - 1)\, d \theta$$

can be derived by replacing $d\theta$ with $d\cos\theta$

$$\begin{align*}
\int^\pi_0 \sin(\theta) \delta(\cos\theta - 1)\, d \theta &= -\int^{-1}_1 \delta(x - 1)\, dx \quad (\text{let } x = \cos\theta, dx = -\sin(\theta)\,d\theta) \\
&= \int^1_{-1} \delta(x - 1)\, dx \\
&= 1
\end{align*}$$

However, if I don't replace the base and apply the definition of Dirac delta ($\int f(x)\delta(x -a)\,dx = f(a)$)directly, the result become $0$.

$$\begin{align*}
\int^\pi_0 \sin(\theta) \delta(\cos\theta - 1)\, d \theta &= \sin(0) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}$$

**What is wrong with the second approach?**

I have seen the other solution that replace $\delta(\cos\theta - 1)$ at [Dirac delta integral of cosx](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627905/dirac-delta-integral-of-cosx)

$$\begin{align*}
\int^\pi_0 \sin(\theta) \delta(\cos\theta - 1)\, d \theta &= \int^\pi_0 \sin(\theta) \frac{\delta(\theta - \frac{\pi}{2})}{|-\sin\frac{\pi}{2}|}\, d \theta \\
&= \int^\pi_0 \sin(\theta) \delta(\theta - \frac{\pi}{2})\, d \theta \\
&= \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) \\
&= 1
\end{align*}$$

**Is the replacement of the Dirac delta function necessary? Why it's required and how is the replacement derived?**

Comment: You can't "apply the definition of Dirac delta directly" because $\delta(\cos\theta-1)\,{\rm d}\theta$ is not of the form $\delta(\theta-a)\,{\rm d}\theta$ for any constant $a$. You don't have to use the rule to replace $\delta$ of a function, but it is the general method and you don't always have nice substitutions like you have here.

Comment: Where can I find the general equation of replacing the Dirac delta function?

Comment: Use the [composition with a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function) property of $\delta$. There is no unambiguous answer to your integral because the delta contribution occurs exactly at an endpoint of the integration $\theta=0$ or $x=1$. Formally, the result is $H(0)$, that is, whichever number you assign to the step function at zero argument

Comment: It is interesting that $H(0)$ is assigned to the different values on [Dirac delta function - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#As_a_measure) and [Heaviside step function - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). One is $1$, and the other is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

What if the second integral method produces the correct result ?

Notice that the third method (with the link) uses the result of $\delta(\cos \theta)$ rather than finding the root of $\delta(\cos \theta - 1)$. The zero should be found from the equation $\cos \theta_{0} = 1$ which gives $0 + 2 \, n \, \pi$ and not the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ given in the example (which is the root of the equation $\cos \theta_{1} = 0)$.

The given integral
$$ \int \sin(a \theta) \, \delta(\cos(a \theta) - b) \, d\theta$$ can be integrated directly by making use of the Heaviside step function as seen by
$$ \int \sin(a \theta) \, \delta(\cos(a \theta) - b) \, d\theta = - \frac{1}{a} \, H(\cos(a \theta) - b) + c_{0}.$$
Evaluating this integral for the limits desired gives
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(a \theta) \, \delta(\cos(a \theta) - b) \, d\theta = \frac{H(1 - b) - H(\cos(a \pi) - b)}{a}. $$
If $a = 1$ then
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(\theta) \, \delta(\cos(\theta) - b) \, d\theta = H(1 - b) - H(-1 - b) $$
and if $b=1$ the result reduces to
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(\theta) \, \delta(\cos(\theta) - 1) \, d\theta = 0. $$

A related integral is given in this question and solution [Integrating Dirac delta functions with trigonometric arguments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698696/integrating-dirac-delta-functions-with-trigonometric-arguments)

Comment: Wow! I need some time to understand Heaviside step function. However, where did I make a mistake in the first method?

Comment: @leucippus Hello my friend!  It's been a long, long while.  I hope all is going well.  As for this result, there is an issue.  For $b=1$, $H(1-b)-H(-1-b)=H(0)-H(-2)=H(0)$.  And $H(0)$ is not uniquely defined.  To that extent, the object $\int_0^\pi \sin(\theta)\delta(\cos(\theta)-1)\,d\theta$ is not well-defined.